# Can't display an image using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

Hi I'm still new with angularjs and spring mvc, My server is working fine When I test it on its own I can see the image but in the client side it's not working and I'm having this error in my console angular.js:3153 GET data:image/JPEG;base64,{} net::ERR_INVALID_URL
 any help please.

ProductController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImg/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void getImg(@PathVariable long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=productImg.png");
        Model model = modelRepo.findById(id);
        model.getUrlImg();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(model.getUrlImg());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        response.setContentType("image");

    }
```

myService.js

```
getImg : function(id)
                        {
                            return $http
                            .get(
                                    'http://127.0.0.1:9001/PrototypePos/rest/products/getImg/'+id,
                                    {responseType : 'arraybuffer'})
                            .then(
                                    function(response) {
                                        return response.data;
                                    },
                                    function(errResponse) {
                                        console
                                                .error('Error while fetching clients');
                                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                    });
                        },
```

myController.js

```
$scope.getImg = function(id,$compileProvider) {
    ProductService.getImg(id).then(function(data) {
        $scope.image=data;
console.log($scope.image +"***************");



    }, function(errResponse) {
        console.error('Error while fetching allPdts');
    });
};
```

In my html code:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}">
```

Comment: Why you save image as data in DB?, you can upload as file in your server

Comment: Well i found this method simpler. But if you have an example well explained please give it to me. It's been hours that' I'm blocked here! and I don't understand the problem

Comment: if you save image as data is too heavy, which language you are using in server side

Comment: I'm using spring-mvc I updated my code abov. You can find my server code

Comment: You can follow this documentation https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810352/how-to-upload-a-multipart-file-using-angular-js-spring-mvc

Comment: You should only be sending the string as text not sending image mime

Comment: Actually I'm getting this error in mmy console                                 angular.js:3153 GET data:image/JPEG;base64,{} net::ERR_INVALID_URL And I didn't understand what should I send as a text not an image mime ??

Comment: why made things so complicated...just do <img ng-src="your_image_url"/>, i.e. <img ng-src="/getImg/{{id}}"/>. BTW, I used the same thing in one of my projects.

Comment: I tried it but still not working:/ I'm doubting ther is a problem with the image returning!!